# Promise flattening fails - why?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

```
const simplePromise = i => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log(i);
        setTimeout(function(){
            resolve();
        }, 2000);
    });
}

var anchor = simplePromise(0);
for (var i=1; i<4; i++) {
    anchor = anchor.then(_ => simplePromise(i));
}
```

prints:

```
0
4
4
4
4
```

instead of:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

**1. Can someone explain why? and 2. tell me how to achieve this?**

I can see that the first promise is executed (*i=0*), then the loop runs and *then* the value of i(*=4*) gets passed to the next promise. Shouldn't this be solved by having a function inside *then* (_ => simplePromise(i)) ?

Comment: Your `for` loop runs to completion.  THEN, the timers fire and the `.then()` handlers run.  So, all the `.then()` handlers run AFTER the `for` loop has completed and thus `i` is at its terminal value.  You could use `let i` instead of `var i` and it would probably fix the output, but I suspect that's not really the main issue here.  You need to understand that promises and timers are not blocking so the `for` loop runs first and schedules everything else to then run later.

Comment: @jfriend00 you've basically repeated my last paragraph.

Comment: Well, apparently you don't understand it though because it's not solved with `then (_ => simplePromise(i))`.  That makes sure that `i` is evaluated LATER when the `.then()` handler is called when it has the terminal value and NOT when the `for` loop is running each iteration.  That's what I'm trying to explain to you.  Remember, the `.then()` callback is called sometime later after the promise resolves.  It's not called while your `for` loop is iterating.  That means it's called after the `for` is done.  That fully explains the output you see.  I'm trying to explain that to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is one of most common mistakes in JS - if not *the* most common - using a `for` loop to manipulate a state variable in an asynchronous situation. Your promises and your loop do not run in sync. The loop finishes much faster than any of your promises do.

Yet you use `i` in your promise callback, which only ever runs after the loop is done. Don't do that. There are ways to prevent it, but this has been discussed so often that I will only suggest to research and read a few of the existing answers.

I strongly suspect that you do not even want to loop over a fixed range of numbers. You actually have an array of items.

Simply drop the `for` loop and use the array iteration tools to dodge the scoping problem. `Array#reduce` is the perfect candidate here.

```js
const simplePromise = val => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(val);
            resolve(val);
        }, 200);
    });
}

var items = [0,1,2,3,4];

console.log("array iteration starts");

items
    .reduce((acc, i) => acc.then(_ => simplePromise(i)), Promise.resolve())
    .then(val => console.log("chain execution end w/ " + val));

console.log("array iteration done");

/*
    acc = Promise.resolve()
      then simplePromise(0)
        then simplePromise(1)
          then simplePromise(2)
            then simplePromise(3)
              then simplePromise(4)
                then console.log("...")
*/
```

Comment: What does `acc` stand for? What if I have more parameters that I would like to pass into simplePromise(..)? Do they have to be part of the `items` array or can I define them before the `Array.reduce`? E.g. a `total` for debugging output a la "processing item 4/15".

Comment: `acc` stands for accumumator. Please read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). I would make anything I wanted to pass to `simplePromise` part of the input array. I'm sure you can figure out where to put the debugging output yourself.

Answer (score 3):

It's happened due you use `var`. Try to change `var` to `let` and that fix your problem.

**UPDATE**

That problem more clearly explained at [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Another_example_of_temporal_dead_zone_combined_with_lexical_scoping) and [this (scroll to section `Difference Details -> Closure in Loop`)](http://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/keyword-var-vs-let/.) and [great explanation of `let` key word](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416/3047033)

**EXPLANATION**

Let take that piece of code:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(i); // output '5' 5 times
  }, 100);  
}
```

In that example each iteration create `function` with closure on variable `i`, which will be executed in the future. Problem is `var` declare variable which

> ...is scoped to the nearest function block and let is scoped to the nearest enclosing block, which can be smaller than a function block.

i.e. all of the created functions will create closure to **the same** variable. And when the execution time comes `i === 5`. And All of the function will print the same value.

How `let` solve that problem...

> `let` in the loop can **re-binds it to each iteration** of the loop, making sure to **re-assign** it the value from the end of the previous loop iteration, so it can be used to **avoid issue with closures**.

Comment: Can you explain why?